# Import setting issues in LR 5.6

Tags: lightroom, import

I changed my import settings to "not allow" in error and now can not import images into my LR 5.6. How do I go back to change my import settings to "allow"?

Answer (score 1):

You can try by reset the warning dialogs in: **Edit->Preferences->General** tab to select "Reset all warning dialogs"
[image]